# How to print contents from 2 different arrays and have items grouped

Tags: java, arrays, grouping, tostring

I'm trying to output a list of all the clubs along with the people entered for each club, but have it display each club individually (i.e. there is one club and the list of people for that club, then the second club entered and the people for that one and so on)

I wanted to make sure the adding of objects to each array was correct and figure out what my `toString()` method should look like.

Here's my code so far:

```
public class app {

    public static Club[] clubArray = new Club[5];
    public static int clubCount=0;
    public static int personCount=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //inside a add method
        //prompt user for club 
        clubArray[clubCount++] = new Club(clubName);

        //prompt user for name, then prompt for Male or Female
        if (x.equals("M")) {
            Male newPerson = new Male(name);
            clubArray[clubCount-1].addPerson(newPerson,personCount);
            personCount++;
        }
    }

    //data definition class
    public class Club { //extend app?
        public static Person[] personArray = new Person[200]; 

        public void addPerson(Person newPerson, int personCount){
            personArray[personCount] = newPerson;
        }
    }
```

Comment: You could use a google guava ArrayListMultiMap - http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/ArrayListMultimap.html which has a structure similar to this Map<Club, ArrayList<Person>>.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a nested for loop

```
for(int x = 0; x < clubArray.length; x++) {
  System.out.println(clubArray[x].getName();
  for(int y = 0; y < clubArray[x].getPeople.length; y++) {
    System.out.println(clubArray[x].getPeople[y].getName();
  }
}
```

I am not sure if your classes are set up this way, but you get the idea. Just iterate through 1 club at a time in the outer for loop, and for the inner loop iterate through each person in that club.

Comment: I'm getting a list of each club but all the members are in each one

Comment: @user3596343 You have set the personArray as static field. This means every club shares the same array of people.

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis then how would my for loop look? because without static it doesnt display any names?

Comment: @user3596343 Try to make the personCount local field of the Club class and remove it from the signature of the addPerson method.

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis I don't think that is it either..The problem I can't figure out is within that nested for loop, when it gets to the second for loop, it goes to the personArray with a new index value and prints out all the people..so how do I get it so that it prints only the contents of clubArray[0] then for clubArray[1] it will pickup where it left off in the student array and print [1]'s people.

Comment: @user3596343 1)Have you removed the 'static' from the personArray and 2) Have you added the personCount as local field on the Club class and removed it from the signature of addPerson?

Comment: @PetrosTsialiamanis yes i just need help to make it so that each club has a separate array of people then the next club

Answer (score 0):

The personArray should not be static. If it is static all the Club instances will share the same array of people. It is better to use List instead of static arrays.

```
public class Club {
     String name;
     List<Person> people = new LinkedList<>();


     public Club(String name) { this.name = name; }         

     public void addPerson(Person p)
     { 
       people.add(p); 
     }         

     public int countPeople()
     {
       return people.size();
     }

     public String toString()
     {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("Club name:").append(name);
        for(Person p : people)
            sb.append(p).append("  ");
        return sb.toString();
     }
}
```

Class Person :

```
public class Person 
{
   private String name;
   private boolean male;

   public Person( String name, boolean male)
   {
      this.name = name;
      this.male = male;
   }

   public String toString() {  ... }
}
```

Class App :

```
public class App
{
    List<Club> clubs = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addClub(Club club)
    { 
       clubs.add(club);
    }

    public String toString()
     {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for(Club c : clubs)
            sb.append(c);
        return sb.toString();
     }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    { 
       App app = new App();

       Club club1 = new Club("ClubName1");
       club1.add(new Person("George", true));
       club1.add(new Person("Mary", false));
       app.addClub(club1);

       Club club2 = new Club("ClubName2");
       club2.add(new Person("Jacob", true));
       club2.add(new Person("Katie", false));
       app.addClub(club2);

       System.out.println(app);

    }
}
```