# printing out objects within objects stored in different arrays using toString (java)

Tags: java, arrays, object, printing, tostring

I'm having the most difficult time trying to output a list of all `clubs` and have the `people` who are in that `club` displayed under it, but it displays all `people` for each `club` instead. I know the problem lies within the nested `for` loop because when it gets to the second `for` loop, it goes to the `personArray` with a new index value and prints out all the people. How do I get it so that it prints only the contents of `clubArray[0]`, then for `clubArray[1]` it will pick up where it left off in the `personArray` and print `clubArray[1]'s` people?

```
public class app {

    public static Club[] clubArray = new Club[5];
    public static int clubCount=0;
    public static int personCount=0;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //inside a add method
        //prompt user for club 
        clubArray[clubCount++] = new Club(clubName);

        //prompt user for name, then prompt for Male or Female
        if (x.equals("M")) {
            Male newPerson = new Male(name);
            clubArray[clubCount-1].addPerson(newPerson,personCount);
            personCount++;
        }

           // .. in a print method
        for(int x = 0; x < clubArray.length; x++) {
              display+= clubArray[x].getClubName();
              for(int y = 0; y < personCount; y++) {
                display += clubArray[x].toString();
              }
            }

    }

    //--------------------------------
    //data definition class

    public class Club { //extend app?
        public static Person[] personArray = new Person[200]; 

        public void addPerson(Person newPerson, int personCount){
            personArray[personCount] = newPerson;
        }

    public String toString() {
    Person personObj = new Person();
    String display= "";
    return display = studentObj.getPersonName();

    }
}
```

Comment: sorry, I mean that for each club it displays everybody in the personArray rather than only displaying those who belong in that club

Comment: you Person[] is static, so it is shared by all the clubs. And i don't see how you distinquish which Person belongs to which Club. did you consider adding clubName property to the Person class and setting it to the appropriate club's name?

Comment: Maybe you can show us how you access the list or people in a club.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to print contents from 2 different arrays and have items grouped](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23429536/how-to-print-contents-from-2-different-arrays-and-have-items-grouped)

Answer (score 1):

The `personArray` in `Club` is declared `static`, which means that there is only one person array, instead of one for each club, which is what you presumably want (each club has an array of all the people in that club).

It would almost certainly be better to have the club have a `List<Person>` so that the list can grow as people are added to the club, instead of having a fixed size of 200 (unless you know that every club will always have exactly 200 people in it).

Comment: what's the best way to get 1 person array for each club?

Comment: Remove the `static` modifier from the declaration of the array.